# Typo in "title" attribute

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spelling

On the main page when you hover over "MONTH" - the tooltip text has a typo:

[image: questions with the most the most views, answers, and votes this month]

> questions with the most the most views, answers, and votes this month

Comment: You're missing the Kanye West quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch, this is now fixed.